# Can I have two .pro files in the same folder?

Tags: c++, qt

***Short Version***

Is it possible to have two .pro file under the same folder?

***Detailed Version***

I'm trying to write unit test using QtTest for one of my projects. The project is Plugin Loader which just loads plugin. So my project Folder looks like:

```
- PluginLoader
 | PluginLoader.pro
 |+bin     // where I have my binary
 |+build   // where I have moc and .o
 |+src     // the actual src for the PluginLoader
 |+test    // some test while I'm developing
 |-unitTest
   | unitTest.pro
   | UnitTest.cpp
   | UnitTest.h
   |-SamplePlugins
     | SamplePluginONE.cpp
     | SamplePluginONE.h
     | SamplePluginTWO.cpp
     .
     .
     .
```

I know the first thing that comes to mind is just to put a `.pro` file in the `SamplePlugins` folder, but I can't do that. The reason for that is, I am ought to use template `.pro` file in 3 different types:

1. Sub-directory template, Only contains the sub directories like `PluginLoader.pro`. Basically it tells Qt to look into sub directories provided in there for some .pro file.
2. Application template, which generates binary and put in `bin` folder. I have on in my `test` folder.
3. Library template, which generates .so and put it in some other path. I use this one in my `src` folder

Now if I want to test my application which only loads some plugins, I need to have some plugins. That's why I have `SamplePlugins` folder under `unitTest` folder.

`UnitTest.pro` has to be from "Application" .pro template so it generates the unittest binary. And the plugin samples should have "Library" .pro so they generate ".so". And that is my dilemma. If I put "Library" .pro file in `SapmlePlugins` then it wont be parse because it's parent folder doesn't have a "Sub-Directory" .pro.

The only way that comes to my mind to overcome this, is to have a "Sub-directory" .pro file in `unitTest`. Then create another folder under `unitTest` and call it `theActualUnitTest` and move the actual unit with its "Application" .pro file into it.  And creat a "Library" .pro in `SamplePlugins` folder. However, I can't do so, because I can't change the foldering, as we have many other projects in the same foldering structure, and some scripts that does some stuff...so changing folder structure is not an option. So I was wondering if it is possible to have two .pro file under a same folder.

Comment: Can you split some portions of the .pro into a .pri file and include it in various .pro files? I know you use Qt Creator, it may not be easily handled (compared to manually written .pro/.pri)

Comment: I already have .pri files within my project directories. I search for the projects dependencies in the .pri files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this is what I did to overcome my issue:

Put a "library" template .pro file in the `SamplePlugins` folder and in the `PluginLoader.pro` which was "sub-directory" template .pro file I asked Qt to look into `unitTest/SamplePlugins` for a another .pro file:

```
SUBDIRS  = src \
           test \
           unitTest \
           unitTest/SamplePlugins \
```

Comment: could you include an ASCII diagram of your file structure, like you did in your question? That would be rather helpful =]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : Yes, did you tried ?

The name of the .pro file is irrelevant, you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, I did. But Creator only show the files in one of them which is `unitTest.pro`. I have the .pro  files in different names...

Comment: Qt Creator only show file that are added to the root or sub .pro file, using include